# Share mouse and keyboard between Linux (ubuntu,) and android?

Tags: android, 22.10

I was looking for and can't find: is there any open source project to share one mouse and keyboard between ubuntu desktop and Android smartphone?

Comment: You're asking for two separate things here. One is to use one mouse and keyboard on both devices. The other, is to expand your Linux desktop to your android device, displaying something on it from the desktop. These are very different (but similar) goals. Can you please clarify what it is you're after? Also, what version of Ubuntu? You tagged 9.10 which is very old and unsupported.

Comment: Check out VNC Server https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/ and VNC Viewer for Android.

Comment: @popey i think what he wants is something like synergy/barrier (its what i want too)